# How to calculate anchor point, when changing transformX value on touchmove event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, css-transforms

I'm creating a slider that displays a panoramic image by moving it horizontally inside a container.

Features or Intention (it's under development):

- By default the animation happens automatically, changing the transformX value, in each step;
- the user's able to touch the element and drag it left or right;
- when touchend event's triggered, the slider resumes the animation from the user's dragged x position;

The problem is that when a user touch the element and starts dragging, the input value on transformX makes the element jumpy, apparently because the anchor point is different every time the user touches the draggable element.

What I'd like to know is, how to calculate the anchor point or position, where the user is dragging from? Or what's the best practice to always calculate from the same point, to avoid having this jumps.

I've done quite a lot of research at the moment without success. You can find a live example in the following link (http://jsbin.com/quhabi/1/edit). Please turn on the `touch emulator` on your brower because at the moment I'm not yet supporting mouse dragging.

You can also have a look into the code below (depends on jQuery):

sass:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #999;

        .panorama {
          width: 80%;
          height: 80%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          overflow: hidden;

          img {
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
            transform-origin:left top;
          }

        }

    }

}
```

html:

```
  <div class="panorama">
       <img src="images/panorama.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
   /*globals $, window */

'use strict';

$('document').ready(function () {

    var panorama = {
        // properties
        $panorama: $('.panorama'),
        $moveElement: $('.panorama img'),
        timestart: 0,
        seconds: 12,
        msTotal: 0,
        direction: -1,
        positionX: 0,
        percentage: 0,
        animationFrameID: false,
        myRequestAnimationFrame: (function () {
            return function (callback) {
                return window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
        })(),
        touchPlayTimeout: 3000,
        moveTimeoutID: null,
        rightBoundary: null,

        // methods
        step: function (timestart) {

            var self = this,
                timestamp,
                positionX;

            timestamp = Date.now();
            self.progress = timestamp - timestart;
            self.percentage = (self.progress * (100 / self.msTotal));

            positionX = self.direction * self.percentage;
            positionX = self.positionBounderies(positionX);
            positionX += '%';

            self.position(positionX);

            if (self.progress < self.msTotal) {
                timestamp += 10;

                self.animationFrameID = self.myRequestAnimationFrame(function () {
                    self.step.call(self, timestart);
                });
            }

        },

        positionBounderies: function (positionX) {

            // move the next line to init method, after image preload done!
            this.rightBoundary = 100 - (100 * (this.$panorama.width() / this.$moveElement.width()));

            positionX = positionX > 0 ? 0 : positionX;
            positionX = (positionX < 0 && Math.abs(positionX) > this.rightBoundary) ? this.direction * this.rightBoundary : positionX;

            return positionX;

        },

        progressByPercentage: function (percentage) {

            return percentage * (this.msTotal / 100);

        },

        dragIt: function (touchX) {

            var positionX,
                percentage = (this.progress * (100 / this.msTotal));

            positionX = this.direction * percentage;
            positionX = positionX + (touchX / 100);
            positionX = this.positionBounderies(positionX);
            positionX += '%';

            // update percentage
            this.percentage = Math.abs(parseFloat(positionX));

            this.position(positionX);
        },

        position: function (posX) {

            this.$moveElement.css('transform', 'translateX(' + posX + ')');

        },

        init: function () {

            var self = this;

            // set initial values
            this.msTotal = this.seconds * 1000;

            // set listeners
            this.$moveElement.on('touchstart mousedown', function (e) {

                // on mousedown prevent browser default `img` drag
                e.preventDefault();

                clearTimeout(self.animationFrameID);
                clearTimeout(self.moveTimeoutID);

            });

            this.$moveElement.on('touchend mouseup', function (e) {

                // on mousedown prevent browser default `img` drag
                e.preventDefault();

                // calculate where to play from using current progress
                var playFrom = null;

                self.progress = self.progressByPercentage(self.percentage);

                self.moveTimeoutID = setTimeout(function () {

                    clearTimeout(self.moveTimeoutID);

                    playFrom = Date.now();
                    playFrom = playFrom - self.progress;

                    self.step(playFrom);

                }, self.touchPlayTimeout);

            });

            this.$moveElement.on('touchmove', function (e) {
                console.log(e);
                var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0],
                    touchPosition = touch.pageX - self.$panorama.width();

                self.dragIt(touchPosition);

            });

            this.step(Date.now());

        }

    };

    panorama.init();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that my problem is related with how I'm calculating the drag `distance`. The code above clearly shows that I'm using solely the position of pageX to calculate the transformX, which is absolutely wrong. The correct way is to store the start point from where the drag is happening from and the current dragging x value should be used to calculate the distance.

For example,

```
    this.$moveElement.on('touchstart mousedown', function (e) {

        var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0];

        self.touchDistance.start = touch.pageX;

    });


    this.$moveElement.on('touchmove', function (e) {

        var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0],
            distance = 0;

        self.touchDistance.end = touch.pageX;

        distance = self.touchDistance.end - self.touchDistance.start;

        self.dragIt(distance);

    });
```

With this, I've got a working solution, as we can see here http://jsbin.com/quhabi/2/edit

Thanks for looking, hope this is useful for someone else in the future!

Comment: LOL, trying to figure out the a similar issue and came up here and found my own answer on this post, that's funny : D